# Lighting in footage oscillates between warm tones and greenish tones

Tags: lighting, color-correction, lightworks

This is my first time posting on this forum.

I do a lot of flatlay filming, timelapses, and my videos tend to have lots of cuts. I've noticed that my film gradually shifts between purple tones to greenish tones during filming, and it is incredibly noticeable during timelapses and when cutting from one point in the video to the next. I use a Canon 70D body, but I've experienced this on a Canon Rebel SL2 and on a Canon EOS 6D Mark ii. It might be a default camera setting on all of the cameras, but I think it is more likely that it is my lighting rig.

I use a LimoStudio lighting rig ( [https://www.amazon.com/LimoStudio-Photography-Lighting-Equipment-AGG814/dp/B00E4YS2XU/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=limostudio&qid=1551213285&s=gateway&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E4YS2XU) ) with fluorescent bulbs. Recently, I bought another lighting rig ( [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00MBVOIJU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MBVOIJU) ) and did a test video to see that this lighting rig produces the same warm to cool oscillation, though not quite as pronounced. So now I'm looking for help because I don't know what else to do.

I film at 60 fps to avoid banding. I usually film at 100 iso and around 5.6 aperture, depending on the lens.

Has anyone else experienced this or found a solution? Is this a fluorescent issue? I am appreciative of anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome! I'm not familiar with those specific cameras, so I can't point you to specific settings, but how have you set the white balance? Did you just leave it in auto? I know there have been some recent improvements, but fluorescents generally have "problematic" spectra. At least for older tube fluorescents, you had to use plusgreen/minusgreen gels to get the color temp right. Have you considered LEDs?